# select grater index in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

This below code selects TD #5 to TD #8 , but I want select TD #2 to TD #4.

How to do this? Help me

```
<table border="1">
    <tr><td>TD #0</td><td>TD #1</td><td>TD #2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>TD #3</td><td>TD #4</td><td>TD #5</td></tr>

    <tr><td>TD #6</td><td>TD #7</td><td>TD #8</td></tr>
</table>
<script>$("td:gt(4)").css("text-decoration", "line-through");</script>
```

Comment: excuse me?!... can you be more clear please.... I don't get `i want select TD #0 to TD #0`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply you can modify your own code for that purpose..
`$("td:lt(5)").css("text-decoration", "line-through");`

for edited question

```
$('td:gt(1):lt(5)').css("text-decoration", "line-through");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('td:lt(1)');
$('td:eq(0)');
$('td:nth-child(1)');
$('td').eq(0);
$('td').slice(0, 1);
```

For the edited question:

```
$('td:gt(1):lt(5)');
$('td').slice(2, 5);
```

Comment: It was for initial version of question (0 to 0) but idea is same

Answer (score 0):

Do you simply mean this?

```
<table border="1">
  <tr><td>TD #0</td><td>TD #1</td><td>TD #2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>TD #3</td><td>TD #4</td><td>TD #5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>TD #6</td><td>TD #7</td><td>TD #8</td></tr>
</table>

<script>
  $("td:lt(1)").css("text-decoration", "line-through");
</script>
```

Or are you trying to get the value of the cell? In chich case, it is very different.

Answer (score 0):

well, you could do a reverse selection by using the `:not()`.

```
<script>$("td:not(:gt(4))").css("text-decoration", "line-through");</script>
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/BxJar/)

but `:lt()` would be perfect. `$("td:lt(5)").css()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select data between specific condition you can use multiple selector like this:

```
$("td:lt(5):gt(1)").css("text-decoration", "line-through");
```

It will select TD #2 to TD #4.

Hope it can help..